# Overriding Uploadify methods

Tags: jquery, uploadify

I'm using the Uploadify jQuery plugin for file uploads. I want to have a custom function to handle files going into the upload queue. I've done this in my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#file-select').uploadify( {
        'swf'      : '/bitstore/public/swf/uploadify.swf',
        'uploader' : 'uploadify.php',
        'queueID'  : 'file-queue',
        'onSelect' : function(file) {
            alert("file added");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

but Uploadify still injects HTML into the DOM to represent the file in the queue. I wanted my custom function to do that itself. Is there a way to stop Uploadify doing this? I thought adding `return false;` to the method would do it, but it's not working.

Thanks.

Comment: See http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/onselect/ - it says Overridable:N/A. Seems you might be out of luck unless you want to go messing with the source.

Comment: I used a previous version of Uploadify and it let me override methods just by returning false like I have. I just assumed the docs weren't completely up-to-date for the new version. Either way I don't know why they'd remove that feature :/

Comment: You could try hiding whatever element Uploadify displays filenames in. Or hack around with the source.

Comment: Just hiding it seems a little hacky. I'll have to edit the source then. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the latest version of Uploadify has disabled overriding of the `onSelect` method (see [onSelect - Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/onselect/)). Your options, then, are to hide the element that Uploadify displays filenames in, *or* you could get in to the source code (use the un-minified version, of course) and see what you can change. As a last resort, you could try using an older version of Uploadify. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find links to any.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer. The new version of Uploadify has changed so you have to set which events you want to override as an option:

http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/overrideevents/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tryied adding the following ?(Didn´t tested) :

```
'onSelect': function(e, q, f) {
        var validExtensions = new Array('doc','docx','pdf');            
        var fileName = f.name;
        var fileNameExt = fileName.substr(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
        if (jquery.inArray(fileNameExt, validExtensions) == -1){
            $(\"#uploadify\").uploadifyCancel(q);
            //$(\"#uploadify\" + q + \" .percentage\").text(\" - Invalid file type\");
            //$(\"#uploadify\" + q).addClass('uploadifyError');               
            return false;
        }
```